# How to design a products database that has different prices depending on the contract

Tags: sql, database, database-design

The title is very vague, so I'll further explain below:

**Context:**

- A manufacturing company has a wide range of **products**, all products have a base price.
- The company has different **contracts** with different **buyers**.
- Each contract contains **a list of products** and **their discounted prices** that the buyer can purchase at. Products not listed in the contract will be purchased at their base price.

In a nutshell, products themselves don't change, but its **price** will change depending on the **contract**. Note that the discounted prices are not calculated by a formula - they are literally a different set of prices.

My product table is setup like this:

```
====================================
product_id | category_id | base_price|  
====================================
 1         |  1          | 300       | 
 2         |  3          | 200       | 
 3         |  5          | 500       |
```

I'm fairly new to database design and for the life of me I can't figure out an efficient way to design the contracts table so that it can change the price of the products that it contains. Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Here's what I've tried:

Contracts table

```
========================
contract_id | buyer_id |  
========================
 1          |  1        | 
 2          |  3        | 
 3          |  5        |
```

Pricings table:

```
===============================================
pricing_id | price | product_id | contract_id |  
===============================================
 1         |  400    | 3        | 1           |
 2         |  230    | 2        | 2           |
 3         |  520    | 5        | 3           |
```

However, wouldn't this approach increase the rows in pricings table dramatically as each products in the contract will be a unique row in this table? So if I had 4 contracts, the rows will be `4 X (No. of products in the contract)`?

Comment: Give us your best shot.  Also `category` should have it's own table.

Comment: just have a prices table indexed by contract. have a default contract which returns the base price.

Comment: @PM77-1 Thanks, updated my approach for your review

Comment: @johnelemans does my approach look fine?

Comment: yes, it does. go for it.

Comment: Design looks almost fine. Remember to create pricings table unique constraint on product_id and contract_id (natural key). Buy the way, your company don't love so much buyer coded as 1. Because +50% charge on product 1 to them.

Comment: @danihp ahahaha thanks mate, it's all about making more money :)

Comment: I will use your question in my next [database designs book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/153735096X/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design looks fine. If you have price for each product on contract then you should to store it. Doesn't matters how big is the table or how many tables you have. Database can deal with this if you have proper design and indexes.

Your design with natural keys:

```
Product         ( id (pk), ..., base_price )
Buyer           ( id (pk), ... )
Contract        ( id, id_buyer (fk1 to Buyer), ... )
Contract_Product( id_contract (pk, FK1 to contract), 
                  id_product (pk, FK2 to product), 
                  price, ... )
```

Your design with surrogate keys:

```
Product         ( id (pk), ..., base_price )
Buyer           ( id (pk), ... )
Contract        ( id, id_buyer (fk1 to Buyer), ... )
Contract_Product( id (pk),
                  id_contract (unique1, FK1 to contract), 
                  id_product (unique1, FK2 to product), 
                  price, ... )
```